# Change property of AppDelegate from UIViewController is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I run into an issue that inside of `AppDelegate`, I create a property to share value within the app.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *currentUser;
```

The definition of `User` object is

```
@property int points;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userName;
```

I have a UIViewController A with a field displaying current user's name. Click on a button will bring up UIViewController B and inside of UIVIewController B, I try to change the values:

```
// I print out these two values here 1
((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).currentUser.userName= @"newName" ;
((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).currentUser.points= 19 ;
// I print out these two values here 2
```

From the print out at 1 and 2, the `userName` has been changed successfully. However, when I pass the control back to A from B, the `userName` field in UIViewController A has not been updated. In my ViewController A, I have:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   textField.text = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).currentUser.userName;
}
```

Any ideas?

Regards
Hammer

---

### UPDATE

it is more weird that, the first line prints 0, second line 13, 3rd line 0 and the last line 13. It looks like the assignment never works. User ID is defined as `@property int userId;`.

```
NSLog(@"BeforeLogin:%d",((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).currentUser.userId);
NSLog(@"newUser.userId:%d",newUser.userId);
// update profile locally
((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).currentUser.userId= newUser.userId ;
NSLog(@"AfterLogin:%d",((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).currentUser.userId);
NSLog(@"newUser.userToken:%@",newUser.userToken);
```

User.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface User : NSObject<HttpClientDelegate>
@property int userId; // I also try @property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) int userId;
```

Comment: Have you allocated and initialized the `currentUser `?

Comment: Yes, as I can already print out its value, just it has not been changed. Sorry, please refer to my updates on the ticket.

Comment: You'll need to show us some more code (e.g. your full `User` .h & .m, where you create the `User` object, how you're printing the values).

Comment: Please refer to my updates on the ticket.

Comment: You should add a call to super in `viewWillAppear:` (`[super viewWillAppear:animated]`).

Comment: Are you sure that viewWillAppear is being executed *after* you change the values?

Comment: Pls refer to my new update

Comment: It's worth to mention, that placing user in the AppDelegate is bad design. It breaks [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for the AppDelegate class. For object required in every place of the app use [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) istead.

Comment: Thomasz, thanks. Yes, agree, thanks for mentioning, though I am still looking for a solution for the issue mentioned above.

Comment: Thomasz, till now I donnot know why AppDelegate does not work. However, after creating a singleton of another class to store the data used within the app, the issue is gone. Pls post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should change your property definition e.g.,

this

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userName;
```

with this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;
```

also take a look at the examples how to define [properties](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/properties-tutorial-for-ios)

Comment: pls read through the update first. Changing to strong does not help. What's more, it is for @property int userId; and it is printed as 0, so its memory has not been released unexpectedly

Comment: oh i didn't see your update but can u pls show the user class header as well

Comment: that happens even if you change it to @property (nonatomic, strong) User *currentUser?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) User *currentUser is not helping. currentUse is initialized through init in AppDelegate and newUser is intialiazed using init before the assigning statement.