# How do I create a single instance of a class and update the data for that one class in many views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating an iPad application that I'll use to conduct surveys among employees. This application will contain multiple UIViewControllers.

What I've done so far:

1. I created a "Survey" class. This class contains properties for fields that I'm going to be filling in as the survey progresses. Basic things like Name, Email Address, Age, etc.
2. I created a subclass for UIViewController called SVViewController. In that class, I created and initialized an instance of Survey called survey after importing the Survey class.
3. I went to each of the UIViewController classes that i already created and associated with a storyboard view and changed their inheritance so that they inherit from SVViewController.

I'm still very new to all this, and I'm having trouble figuring out how I'm going to proceed. I want the instance of Survey (again, called "survey") to contain all the data as the user fills it in. When somebody enters their name in the first view, I want it to communicate back to that instance of survey to update the name. I then want to go into the next view and pull that value of "name" from the instance of survey.

Basically, I need survey, this one instance of Survey, to persist throughout all views. I found an example online regarding a singleton pattern, and I started with that, but I'm having some trouble. Before I go any further, I will paste some code:

```
Survey.h
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface Survey : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *emailAddress;
    @end


Survey.m
    #import "Survey.h"
    @implementation Survey
    @end

SVViewController.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "Survey.h"
    @interface SVViewController : UIViewController {
    Survey *survey;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Survey *survey;
    +(id)sharedManager;
    @end


SVViewController.m

    #import "SVViewController.h"
    @interface SVViewController ()
    @end

    @implementation SVViewController
    @synthesize survey;
    +(id)sharedManager{
        static SVViewController *sharedSVViewController = nil;
        @synchronized(self){
            if(sharedSVViewController == nil)
                sharedSVViewController = [[self alloc]init];
        }
        return sharedSVViewController;
    }
    - (id) init{
        if(self = [super init]){
            survey = [[Survey alloc] init];
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @end
```

I'm sure this is kind of a mess, and I tried toying around with it for a long time. I think that what's happening is that the single instance of Survey is being created, but when I try to do things like setting values to the properties of Survey (name, emailAddress, etc) and then rewrite them to check to see if they changed, I'm just getting nulls back. I'm assuming that this is because I'm not initializing the property anywhere, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out where to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a single instance of `Survey`, but it looks like you have written code to create a single instance of `SVViewController`. Instead, try this:

```
@interface Survey : NSObject
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *emailAddress;
@end

@implementation Survey
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
  static Survey *_instance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _instance = [[Survey alloc] init];
  });
  return _instance;
}
@end
```

Comment: Okay, I'm with you so far, but if I want the instance of Survey to be visible to my other UIViewControllers, I have to include an instance of Survey in the parent class (SVViewController), right? I see that your codeblock lists _instance=[[Survey alloc]init], which seemingly would do it, but how do I include that instance of Survey so that it's visible? Did I make a mistake by creating a new subclass of UIViewController and changing the inheritance?

Comment: The selector `[Survey sharedInstance]` can be accessed in any class. It's a static method on `Survey` which provides you the singleton instance.

Answer (score 2):

To share data within the app, you may want to use singleton. For example, create a .h and .m named CommonData, in.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class User; // for your case, you may want to use Survey

@interface CommonData : NSObject

@property (strong) User *currentUser;  // this is to store data used across all UIViewController

+ (CommonData *)sharedModel;

@end
```

in.m

```
#import "CommonData.h"
#import "User.h"

@implementation CommonData
@synthesize currentUser;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        currentUser = [[User alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (CommonData *)sharedModel
{
    static CommonData *_sharedModel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceSecurePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&onceSecurePredicate,^
                  {
                      _sharedModel = [[self alloc] init];
                  });

    return _sharedModel;
}

@end
```

Whenever you want to set or get, access the data through [CommonData sharedModel].currentUser.xxx . I used to use AppDelegate to store the data shared within the app. However, I run into some weird issues (see [Change property of AppDelegate from UIViewController is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524445/change-property-of-appdelegate-from-uiviewcontroller-is-not-working)). Using the Singtelon instead so far so good. Hope it helps.

Regards
Hammer